# Linq to Entities and Linq to XML

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML structure in form of XDocument:

```
<Header><person><ID>0888-123-45</ID><Name>Joe</Name><LocationID>Loc1</LocationID><LocationName>New York</LocationName><CarName>Honda</CarName><CarYear>2000</CarYear></person><person><ID>199-20-333</ID><LocationID>My House</LocationID><LocationName>My House</LocationName><CarName>BMW</CarName><CarYear>2011</CarYear></person></Header>
```

There are 3 entities involved:

**Person**:

- GUID, ID (varchar), Name (varchar), LocationID (Location's GUID)

**Car**:

- GUID, PersonID (Person's GUID), CarName (varchar), CarYear (varchar)

**Location**:

- GUID, LocationID (varchar), LocatioName (varchar)

What I want to achieve is the following steps:

1. Get distinct locations for all persons in XDocument
2. If location in XDocument exists in data context, don't insert, else insert
3. Insert all persons and their corresponding car.

This is what I have and it is throwing an error since the query is a mix of both Linq to Entities and Linq to XML.  I appreciate for any insight and suggestion for a better way to solve it.  No for loops as parsing XDocument with for loops is slow.

```
        Dim fileLocs = (From p In xmlDoc.<Header>.<Person>
                        Select New location With {.locID = Guid.NewGuid(), _
                                                  .locationID = If(p.<LocationID> Is Nothing, Nothing, p.<LocationID>.Value), _
                                                  .locLabel = If(p.<LocationName> Is Nothing, Nothing, p.<LocationName>.Value)})
        Dim filteredFileLocs = From l In fileLocs
                               Where l.locationID IsNot Nothing AndAlso l.locationID <> "" AndAlso
                                    (From loc In ctx.locations
                                      Where loc.locationID = l.locationID AndAlso loc.locLabel = l.locLabel
                                      Select loc).Count = 0
                              Select l

        Dim sysLocs = (From loc In ctx.locations Select loc)
        Dim allLocs = filteredFileLocs.Union(sysLocs)

        Dim pers As IEnumerable(Of person) = (From p In xmlDoc.<Header>.<Person>
                                            Select New Person With {.personID = Guid.NewGuid(), .ID = p.Element(XName.Get("ID")).Value, _
                                                                    .locID = If(p.<locationID> IsNot Nothing AndAlso p.<locationID>.Value <> "", CType(Nothing, Guid?), _
                                                                                    (From sl In allLocs
                                                                                    Where sl.locationID = p.Element(XName.Get("LocationID")).Value AndAlso
                                                                                        sl.locLabel = p.Element(XName.Get("LocationName")).Value
                                                                                    Select sl.locID)), _
                                                                    .Name = p.Element(XName.Get("Name")).Value})


        For Each l In filteredFileLocs
            ctx.locations.AddObject(l)
        Next
        For Each p In pers
            ctx.persons.AddObject(p)
        Next
```

Error is on the line Dim pers: "Specified cast is not valid."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I noticed is that the clause where .locID is set,

```
(From sl In allLocs Where sl.locationID = p.Element(XName.Get("LocationID")).Value

AndAlso sl.locLabel = p.Element(XName.Get("LocationName")).Value Select sl.locID)
```

is returning an ienumberable and it's assigned to .LocID which is a GUID, so that should be the error cause, you would need to add FirstOrDefault, First, SingleOrDefault or Single like this

```
(From sl In allLocs Where sl.locationID = p.Element(XName.Get("LocationID")).Value

AndAlso sl.locLabel = p.Element(XName.Get("LocationName")).Value _

Select sl.locID).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks! Also how I find out which person a car belongs to is inserting XElement of GUID for each person first then as I initialize all the Cars, I do : .PersonID = GUID.Parse(c.Parent.<GUID>.Value).  Better solutions are always welcome!